# how to get the modified input back in a prefix notation

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that performs math.
As input, I got a prefix notation such as `['+',['-',['multiply',3,5],8],2]`.

My problem after I perform the most inner operation, how can I get my original input back modified? For instance, here what I expect from my code is that it multiplies `3` with `5`,(`=15`) substracts `8` from the result, and finally adds `2` to it. To do this, I firstly calculate `['multiply',3,5]`. And after I have to run function with the input `['+',['-',15,8],2]`. However hours passed and I could not find a way.

```
def kenobi(k):
    def think(k):   
        if type(k[1]) == int:
            k = calculator(k)
            return kenobi(k) #here I actually want to return [+,[-,15,8],2]
        if type(k[1][0]) == str:
            return kenobi(k[1][1])

    def calculator(k):
        if k[0] == '*':
            k = k[1]*k[2]
            return k
        if k[0] == '-':
            k = k[1]-k[2]
            return k
        if k[0] == '+':
            k = k[1]+k[2]
            return k
    return think(k)

print kenobi(['+',['-',['*',3,5],8],2])
```

Comment: From Arman: You should use Stack

Best way to store variables inside function calls is a stack , here is an example of this : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/228915-infixpostfix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive function by checking if there is another list to go into. If not then do the math operation and replace the position of the list you just calculated with the answer

```
import operator
def kenobi(l):
    if isinstance(l[1],list):
        l[1] = kenobi(l[1])
    return do_math(l)

def do_math(l):
    #print l
    ops = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.div}
    return ops[l[0]](l[1],l[2])

print kenobi(['+',['-',['*',3,5],8],2])

9
```

alternatively if you are going to have lists that aren't at index 1 then you can alter it to this

```
import operator

def kenobi(l):
    ops = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.div}

    for i in xrange(1,len(l)):
        if isinstance(l[i],list):
            l[i] = kenobi(l[i])

    return ops[l[0]](l[1],l[2])

print kenobi(['+',['-',['*',['*',5,5],['+',3,5]],8],2])

194
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a very simple evaluation strategy. First, note that the prefix notation defines a *tree*:

```
      +
     / \
    -   2
   / \
  *   8
 / \
3   5
```

Therefore it's attractive to build that tree and evaluate it recursively:

```
def evaluate(root):
    if root == '+':
        return evaluate(left) + evaluate(right)
    elif root == '-':
        return evaluate(left) - evaluate(right)
    elif root == '*':
        return evaluate(left) * evaluate(right)
    elif root == '/':
        return evaluate(left) / evaluate(right)
    else:
        return root
```

You don't have to build a tree, though:

```
def evaluate(seq):
    if type(seq) == list:
        op, left, right = seq[0], seq[1], seq[2]

        if op == '+':
            return evaluate(left) + evaluate(right)
        elif op == '-':
            return evaluate(left) - evaluate(right)
        elif op == '*':
            return evaluate(left) * evaluate(right)
        elif op == '/':
            return evaluate(left) / evaluate(right)
    else:
        return seq
```